# How to make default value get selected in yii dropdown list

Tags: yii

I am using an yii `dropDownList` for creating a drop-down in my form. I want one value for example `'78'=>'selected'` gets default selected in drop-down .My drop down is

```
dropDownList($testcontroller,'testid',CHtml::listData(Phases::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('pid'=>$pid)), 'id', 'phaseName'));
```

Can any one help me in doing this

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
dropDownList($testcontroller,
  'testid',
   CHtml::listData(Phases::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('pid'=>$pid)), 
  'id', 
  'phaseName'),
   array('options' => array('78'=>array('selected'=>true))));
```

**if its coming from database, use something like below (in case of list box or multiple allowed `dropDownList` use `multiple=>true`)**

```
foreach ($selections as $eachValue)
  $selectedOptions[$eachValue] = array('selected'=>'selected');

echo  $form->dropDownList($model,
      'testid', 
       CHtml::listData(Phases::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('pid'=>$pid)),
      'id',
      'phaseName'),
      array('multiple'=>'true','prompt'=>'select ','options'=>$selectedOptions));
```

**More details about dropDownList : [dropDownList() method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail)**

Comment: It is working for simple dropDownList but not working for multiple dropDownList.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by passing this in your html options of dropdown..

`dropDownList($testcontroller,
  'testid',
   CHtml::listData(Phases::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('pid'=>$pid)), 
  'id', 
  'phaseName'),
   array('options' => array('78'=>array('selected'=>true))));`

and the value 78 will be selected.

for prompt one can do something like this:

`dropDownList($testcontroller,'testid', CHtml::listData(Phases::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'phasename'), array('empty'=>'Select an option'));`

check this for [help](http://yiihelp.blogspot.in/2012/05/default-selected-value-in-dropdownlist.html). Thanks.

Comment: It will generate `<option value="">78</option>`
not `<option value="78">abcdefg</option>`

Comment: Corrected the answer

Answer (score -1):

suppose you want to show drop down of `menu_name`  from `Menu model` and selected value on the basses of `parent_menu_id` then you can use it like this

```
 <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'parent_menu_id', CHtml::listData(Menu::model()->findAll(), 'menu_id', 'menu_name'), array('empty'=>'--please select--')); ?>
```